# Is there a sum function for strings in Microsoft ODBC?

Tags: sql, excel, group-by, odbc

I was having trouble with this idea that floated through my head. I tried testing it and now I'm a bit stuck.
So for example, there is a table with 3 columns:

1st column that is unique to each item

2nd column that is deciding where that item will end up being located so this can have duplicates

3rd column that has a description of the item

If this was quantifiable, I believe you could use an aggregate sum. But what if, you want to show no duplicates, just one number, and then add all the strings together based on the 2nd column.

[image]

Thus the output will now look like this:

[image]

I want to do this in SQL based on Microsoft ODBC. So if the data refreshes, it will just output this.

Anything will help, thanks guys!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you running? And, if you are running SQL Server, why did you tag your question `ms-access`?

Comment: Well, Im using excel, and using the Microsoft Servers. I found that a lot of the SQL that I write is a lot similar to ms-access.

Comment: The term you need is "concatenate strings", not "sum strings" (1 + 2 = 3, not 12)., although you can use the`+`operatot instead of`&`, but that can lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running SQL Server 2017, you can use aggregate function `string_agg()`:

```
select column2 duplicates, string_agg(column3, ',') within group(order by column1) str
from mytable
group by column2
```

In earlier versions, you can use `for xml path` as follows;

```
select
    column2 duplicates,
    stuff(
        (
            select ',' + t1.column3
            from mytable t1
            where t1.column2 = t.column2
            for xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
    ) str
from mytable t
group by column2
```